# Are there negative impacts to using constants in SwiftUI View structs?

Tags: swift, swiftui

A coworker is claiming that we should not use constants in SwiftUI View structs. Even for properties of a value type where the value will not change.

For example, they say this is not good:

```
struct FlagView: View {
    let flagIcon = Image(systemName: "flag")
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            flagIcon
            Text("Flags")
            flagIcon
        }
    }
}
```

But do this instead:

```
struct FlagView: View {
    var flagIcon: Image { Image(systemName: "flag") }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            flagIcon
            Text("Flags")
            flagIcon
        }
    }
}
```

Their explanation sounds like [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) based on their misinterpretation of Apple tutorial code and ignorance of fundamentals. However, proving that is elusive. Apple documentation is not going to explain every crazy thing we should **not** do because that is an infinite list.

Or maybe there is magic in SwiftUI I am ignorant of.

Is their assertion correct? If yes or no, please explain why.

Note, I realize this is a simplistic example and really we would type the `Image` out twice in the `VStack`. I am trying to focus on the general case.

Comment: Values yes, objects no, macros like your example?...it depends what the macro does.

Comment: @malhal I will create a different example. As an FYI, Swift does not have macros. That is a func in Foundation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1418095-nslocalizedstring

Comment: you and your co-worker may be talking about 2 different things: for you `let ...` is just the way to say "it's a property, and it's not going to change". Your co-worker probably thinks about optimization: SwiftUI views are very short lived, they are potentially recreated on any state change, and storing anything in them that is supposed to live longer than 1 view render is fruitless. So he says "putting a constant in a view has no benefit". You both have your point...

Comment: Image actually has an extension making it a View so probably the second version is best. As long as it doesn't use state for the image name.

Comment: This is why I like the third option: never any constants in any class or struct! If you want class-specific constants, define `private enum Constants` (or whatever the name fits) and put them there. If you have reusable constants, create an internal enum and put them there. Fortunately my co-workers agree with me on that :)

Comment: @sfgblackwarkrts wrote: "SwiftUI views are...potentially recreated on any state change..." That's the closest to a reasonable explanation so far. Thanks.

Comment: Further…why have an instance property that does not depend on any instance data?

Comment: @Jessy that’s my fault for a simplistic example. I struggled to contrive an example that was short but valid. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

In their typical fashion, Apple have frustratingly hidden vital info in WWDC videos. After scouring them all day, I have found to my surprise that Apple has addressed this exact topic at least twice. My coworker's misapprehension must be common because Apple felt the need to clarify.

1. [WWDC20 *Introduction to SwiftUI*](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10119/)
2. [WWDC20 *Data Essentials in SwiftUI*](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040)

From *Introduction to SwiftUI*:

> And technically, any constant can serve as a perfectly good read-only source of truth. The test data driving our previews is an example of this.

[image: 4 squares showing sources of truth types]

From *Data Essentials in SwiftUI*

> And how will the view manipulate this data? It just displays the data, it doesn't change it, so these can be "let" properties.

[image: View source code highlighting let]

> Your data's lifetime is important, but that lifetime is tied to the lifetime of its source of truth, and in all of the previous examples, we've used tools like State, StateObject, and Constants.

[image: 3 buttons showing types of source of truth]